# Scroll down with follow up

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I made this site.

If I scroll down, I want the green bar to scroll down too... so it has to follow up.

How do i do that?

Code of the green bar:

```
 <div class="box">
<a href="tel:06118608775">Bel ons nu!</a></div>
```

cs:

```
.box {
  background: #2db34a;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 95px;
  line-height: 95px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100%;
}
.box:hover {
  background: #ff7b29;
}
```

Comment: yes my englisch is garbage sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I scroll down, I want the green bar to scroll down too

You don't need to script this.

Simply give the green bar `position: fixed` in your CSS.

**Working Example:**

```css
header {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,91,0);
}

header + p {
margin-top: 96px;
}
```

```html
<header>
Green Bar
</header>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at usu inermis reformidans. Ne vis dictas vidisse, te labitur deserunt vix. Cu sit quando appetere postulant, est eu ullum omnium, ut eius ceteros accusamus qui. Cum etiam facete persequeris in. Sea eu possim offendit. Duo idque oportere et.</p>
<p>Harum epicurei eum ea, habeo numquam iracundia quo ne. Doctus elaboraret eum ei, integre ceteros disputando sit eu. Vim in probo ullamcorper. Pri detracto ullamcorper at, facete detraxit facilisi nam id. Unum eruditi perpetua ex eam, aeque aliquid qui ex.</p>
<p>Mea iudico epicurei ne, no possim cetero mel, at sumo intellegat vix. Vel assum libris te. Nihil pertinacia intellegebat his an, id novum propriae placerat per, vis an nusquam volutpat constituam. His ex equidem accusata democritum. Ex nam choro soluta essent.</p>
<p>Eam volumus consulatu molestiae ei, molestie suscipit eos cu, pro no saepe forensibus. Mel consulatu disputationi cu. No aliquip antiopam efficiendi quo, ius ea tation electram. Sit impedit accusam legendos ne, ne semper mnesarchum pri.</p>
<p>Vide possim vim ut. Ludus expetendis id pri, choro nonumy eu pri. Dictas eruditi constituto cu mea, mei decore inimicus oportere ex. At est nibh nonumy, ut his aliquid dolores. Usu hinc inermis eligendi eu.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at usu inermis reformidans. Ne vis dictas vidisse, te labitur deserunt vix. Cu sit quando appetere postulant, est eu ullum omnium, ut eius ceteros accusamus qui. Cum etiam facete persequeris in. Sea eu possim offendit. Duo idque oportere et.</p>
<p>Harum epicurei eum ea, habeo numquam iracundia quo ne. Doctus elaboraret eum ei, integre ceteros disputando sit eu. Vim in probo ullamcorper. Pri detracto ullamcorper at, facete detraxit facilisi nam id. Unum eruditi perpetua ex eam, aeque aliquid qui ex.</p>
<p>Mea iudico epicurei ne, no possim cetero mel, at sumo intellegat vix. Vel assum libris te. Nihil pertinacia intellegebat his an, id novum propriae placerat per, vis an nusquam volutpat constituam. His ex equidem accusata democritum. Ex nam choro soluta essent.</p>
<p>Eam volumus consulatu molestiae ei, molestie suscipit eos cu, pro no saepe forensibus. Mel consulatu disputationi cu. No aliquip antiopam efficiendi quo, ius ea tation electram. Sit impedit accusam legendos ne, ne semper mnesarchum pri.</p>
<p>Vide possim vim ut. Ludus expetendis id pri, choro nonumy eu pri. Dictas eruditi constituto cu mea, mei decore inimicus oportere ex. At est nibh nonumy, ut his aliquid dolores. Usu hinc inermis eligendi eu.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at usu inermis reformidans. Ne vis dictas vidisse, te labitur deserunt vix. Cu sit quando appetere postulant, est eu ullum omnium, ut eius ceteros accusamus qui. Cum etiam facete persequeris in. Sea eu possim offendit. Duo idque oportere et.</p>
<p>Harum epicurei eum ea, habeo numquam iracundia quo ne. Doctus elaboraret eum ei, integre ceteros disputando sit eu. Vim in probo ullamcorper. Pri detracto ullamcorper at, facete detraxit facilisi nam id. Unum eruditi perpetua ex eam, aeque aliquid qui ex.</p>
<p>Mea iudico epicurei ne, no possim cetero mel, at sumo intellegat vix. Vel assum libris te. Nihil pertinacia intellegebat his an, id novum propriae placerat per, vis an nusquam volutpat constituam. His ex equidem accusata democritum. Ex nam choro soluta essent.</p>
<p>Eam volumus consulatu molestiae ei, molestie suscipit eos cu, pro no saepe forensibus. Mel consulatu disputationi cu. No aliquip antiopam efficiendi quo, ius ea tation electram. Sit impedit accusam legendos ne, ne semper mnesarchum pri.</p>
<p>Vide possim vim ut. Ludus expetendis id pri, choro nonumy eu pri. Dictas eruditi constituto cu mea, mei decore inimicus oportere ex. At est nibh nonumy, ut his aliquid dolores. Usu hinc inermis eligendi eu.</p>
```

Comment: it worked but the green bar is now behind the SLIDER. I want it to the front end

Comment: Try adding a z-index to the green bar. It needs to have a higher z-index than anything which should appear behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the box-class:

```
.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using position:fixed in your css:

```
.box {
  position:fixed;
}
```